# How to split excel data by region and mail fractions to appropriate addresses from SAS?

Tags: excel, sas, email-attachments

I have prepared a dataset in sas and exported in the .xlsx format to a location on my computer. I'm able to send mail with the attachment which i have exported. I wanted to know if there's a possibility to apply a 'where' condition to a column(Region in this case,having 4 values -W,E,S,N) in the excel via sas programming and attach the filtered (specific records , like data for W,S only etc) excel file to an appropriate email address? Kindly help.I'm attaching the code written on SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1 for single recipient which sends the unfiltered excel and the image of the sample data. [image]

```
options emailsys = smtp
    emailid = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
    emailpw = 'xxxx'
    emailhost = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    emailport = 587 ;

options emailhost=(
    'smtp.gmail.com'
    STARTTLS auth=LOGIN
    id='xxxx@gmail.com'
    pw='xxxx' port=587
);
filename f_email email
    to = 'xxxx@jkl.com'
    from = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
    subject = 'Test'
    attach=("D:\abc\xxxx.xlsx"  content_type="application/xlsx");

data _null_;
    file f_email;
    put 'Test';
run;
```

Regards,
sklal

Comment: Can you explain the location of data some more ?  Is the attachment information in SAS data sets (and thus the .xlsx is created by SAS) ? Is the region/recipient in SAS data sets (I presume yes) ? Update the question with some sample data.

Comment: This is way too much for a single question, and too disorganized.  One question per question please, and you need to do a lot more before asking the first question I suspect.

Comment: Before you generalize, get one case working first. Break it down into the smallest steps you can and get each step working - how to email data with an attachment. How to create attachment/export data for each region. I answered this last question on communities.sas.com yesterday.

Comment: @Richard - The attachment information is present in the SAS dataset and from it, the excel is created. The region column is present in the dataset. I'll update the question with an image of the sample data. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Joe - Thanks for your input. I'll keep them in mind.

Comment: @Reeza - Thanks for your input. I was able to send the mail with attachment. Just wanted to know if the excel could be filtered via programming and could be sent to different addresses. I have reframed the problem statement, hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter the excel file before sending it, You'll have to create one excel file for each region and attach it separately.

Steps:

1. Read the excel file in SAS and save to a work table
2. Filter/breakdown the table in to four tables: north,south,east, west
3. Export your four tables to four excel files
4. Repeat the above code four times or create a macro function for your email code.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not possible to filter the excel after it is created via programming? The steps worked for me (wrote a macro for the email code).

Comment: If you use the Put Statement you will still be conditionally sending files, you will still have to specify which file to attach.

Comment: @sklal it depends on what you mean by filter the Excel after creation. If you're talking about removing records, that doesn't make sense because you're undoing work. If you're talking about applying an Excel filter to the data that's an entirely different question that did not come across in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need "PUT Statement Email Directives'.

http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n0ig2krarrz6vtn1aw9zzvtez4qo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n1rxu4polvqoy3n13t1ado2vfcyd